# Unable to run test cases in Testrail from Cypress

Tags: cypress, testrail

I have correctly followed the steps and added cypress-testrail-reporter. When I run my test in cypress nothing happens in Testrail.

```
"reporter": "cypress-testrail-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "domain": "server address",
    "username": "email",
    "password": "pass",
    "projectId": 1,
    "suiteId": 1,
  }
```

I am also correctly assigning the test case id it("C123 is the test case id",...).

Enabled API is also checked in TestRail/Administration/View system log I do not see any strange thing.

In the past, I have successfully integrated the C# code with testrail to run my test cases.

I have also successfully tested protractor - TestRail integration.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it was not working. I was not using dashboard. The run worked after getting the project Id and key.